# Does Dispatcher.Invoke block on the calling thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I was wondering if, when calling Dispatcher.Invoke, the calling thread would wait until the dispatcher finished its operation or not...?

For example:

```
new Thread(() =>
{
   string x = "Yes.";
   // Invoke the dispatcher.
   Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate()
   {
      // Get the string off a UI element which contains the text, "No."
      x = textBox.Text;
   });
   // Is x either ("Yes" or "No") here, or always "No"?
}).Start();
```

Comment: Why won't you try it? Add a sleep of a couple of seconds inside the invoke, another line out of it, and see if it hits it before it's done ...

Comment: @Noctis You know what, I am so tired right now that...that didn't even cross my mind, but I'll give it a shot I guess. It wouldn't hurt to have someone reference some tangible documentation on this though :P

Comment: Nothing like coding into the small hours, eh?

Comment: Nah ...just answered your question for you ... it's back to the code mines for you !

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like it will block :)

Have a look here: [Dispatcher.Invoke from a new thread is locking my UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8527778/dispatcher-invoke-from-a-new-thread-is-locking-my-ui)

Here's some more wisdom:

> Invoke is synchronous and BeginInvoke is asynchronous. The operation is added to the event queue of the Dispatcher at the specified DispatcherPriority.

Comment: #CodeMonkeysUnite. Thanks, Noctis. Nice find! Back to slavery I go.

Comment: *whip lashing* ... :) Glad I could help... wait ...what ?? it's only 2130 in toronto !!! *quick minions, fetch some coke and pizza for this one !!!*

Comment: Hahahah, hey man, if I had warm weather all year round I'd have a lot more energy!

Comment: Aychiuwawa !! 6-4 celsius? I'll stick with answering your tired questions from my 26-18 (plus thunderstorms!) :)

Comment: Send over some minions!